# Given what happened in S08E03, is the Azor Ahai prophecy a false prophecy?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* S08E03,

> Arya Stark stabbed the Night King.

But it was told that the Azor Ahai, the prince/princess who was promised, would bring an end to the Long Night.

So, is Arya the Azor Ahai? If yes, then why did Jon Snow come back to life, what was the big reason?